# Repeat until predicate evaluates to true in prolog

Tags: prolog

So, I am pretty new to prolog and am having troubles doing some very basic thing. I want to be able to repeat the evaluation of a predicate until in evaluates to `True`.

```
do(Goals, Frontier, Explored):-
    repeat, bfs(Goals, Frontier, Explored).
```

Basically the predicate `bfs` will evaluate to `False` most of the time (due to some random path search it takes different values). And I want to stop looking once it evaluates to `True`. The predicate `do` is basically acting as a `while` loop here. When the predicates evaluates to True, I want the loop to end.

Though there are some other posts on stackoverflow addressing this issue I find them hard to understand since they go into details about their own issues. So maybe someone can just show me a general recipe for this scenario.

Comment: though the loop doesn't *end* when the predicate succeeds, the loop does stop --- the result is produced and then the "loop" pauses, ready to resume the search from the point where it stopped. if you don't want it to proceed, don't request that of it. if you don't want it to be able to proceed, add a cut `!` after its invocation, or even inside `do` as its last goal, after the `bfs` call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you already wrote the solution!

This is a "failure-driven loop".

Prolog behaves as if there was a cursor moving from left to right (ok, here, top to bottom due to formatting) through the line, The cursor is sent back to the left when a predicate call fails, and bounces off back to the right at [`repeat/0`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=repeat/0):

```
do(X) :-                                 % X will take on the value of success
  repeat ,                               % The cursor bounces off here
                                         % ...to try again!                  
  format("Now trying something\n",[]) ,     
  random(0.0,1.0,X) ,                    % Try something
  format("Obtained ~q\n",[X]) ,            
  X < 0.2 ,                              % Test whether success
  format("Done!\n").                     % On success, we end up here.
                                         % On failure, we redo in order
                                         % Redo X < 0.5 - There is no redo here
                                         % Redo format/2 - There is no redo here 
                                         % Redo random/3 - There is no redo here  
                                         % Redo format/2 - There is no redo here 
                                         % Redo repeat/1 - Redo means cursor bounce
```

And so:

```
?- do(X).
Now trying something
Obtained 0.9837293974501616
Now trying something
Obtained 0.7031039796418066
Now trying something
Obtained 0.5838475489280747
Now trying something
Obtained 0.7179787440277113
Now trying something
Obtained 0.14040275695848495
Done!
X = 0.14040275695848495
```

As there is no "cut", the Prolog toplevel will ask whether you want more solutions. If you enter `;`, the process continues, re-entering at `format("Done!\n")`.

Here is an alternative which

- Uses [`between/3`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=between/3) to do maximally 4 tries
- At first success, cuts off further solutions/retries with '!', so the user is never asked for a second attempt.

```
do(X) :-  
  between(1,4,K) ,            
  format("Now trying something, K = ~q\n",[K]) ,     
  random(0.0,1.0,X) ,
  format("Obtained ~q\n",[X]) ,            
  X < 0.2 ,                   
  format("Done!\n"),
  !.
```

Due to the "redo-limiting" nature of `between/3`, this can actually fail after a finite number of redos:

```
?- do(X).
Now trying something, K = 1
Obtained 0.823698968756448
Now trying something, K = 2
Obtained 0.8617406555236128
Now trying something, K = 3
Obtained 0.7718447437621774
Now trying something, K = 4
Obtained 0.6010951752269867
false.
```

**Bonus Brain Teaser**

This predicate also prints something when the "cursor moves to the left".

It may not be directly evident how it works.

```
do(X) :-  
  between(1,4,K) ,            
  (true ; (format("Going to hit between/3 coming from the 'right' with K = ~q\n",[K]),fail) ), 
  format("Now trying something, K = ~q\n",[K]) ,     
  random(0.0,1.0,X) ,
  format("Obtained ~q\n",[X]) ,            
  (true ; (format("NOPE! ~q doesn't cut it\n",[X]),fail) ), 
  X < 0.2,                   
  format("Done!\n"),
  !.
```

Sample output:

```
?- do(X).
Now trying something, K = 1
Obtained 0.25501790245795947
NOPE! 0.25501790245795947 doesn't cut it
Going to hit between/3 coming from the 'right' with K = 1
Now trying something, K = 2
Obtained 0.2778042792426882
NOPE! 0.2778042792426882 doesn't cut it
Going to hit between/3 coming from the 'right' with K = 2
Now trying something, K = 3
Obtained 0.042750567384520134
Done!
X = 0.042750567384520134.
```